# BigInteger.ToString in scientific notation (i.e. with E)

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

`Double.ToString` on a very large number usually returns only a number of significant digits, followed by the exponent notation with a power of ten. However, *BigInteger* doesn't do this, and simply returns all digits of the number.

How can I tell it to output only in the scientific format like double does instead of the full number? I can't convert it to double, because it is greater than *Double.MaxValue*. I could build a formatting function myself, but I would be happier if there was a built-in feature taking all cultures into account.

Comment: Does the format string "E" not work for BigInteger?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268260(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Baldrick I knew the answer would be simple. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, just wish I'd posted the answer myself now! ;)

Comment: Dear downvoters, mind you explain you finding this question being of poor quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply be able to use the [`BigInteger.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268260(v=vs.110).aspx) method along with the [expected Exponential formatting string `E`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle scientific notation :

```
var input = BigInteger.Parse("12498124912841982142441242424421");
var output = input.ToString("E"); // yields "1.249812E+031"
```

Answer (score 4):

Like most `ToString` methods, [BigInteger.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268260(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to pass a *format string*:

```
var myString = myBigInteger.ToString("E"); // yields exponential notation
```

See the following MSDN page for a detailed description of the built-in numeric format strings available in .NET:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note that the [Exponential Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#EFormatString) allows you to provide an optional *precision* specifier.